# WCF Interface service contract instance calling a function directly

Tags: c#, wcf

I have class (named Sender) that has a member of Icommunicator interface which defines a WCF Service Contract.

```
public class Sender
{
    private ICommunicator channel;
    private ChannelFactory<ICommunicator> factory = null;
```

Inside the same .cs file there's a `class Receiver` which inherits from Icommunicator.

The interface that defines the service contract is as follow:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "P2PComm")]
public interface ICommunicator
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PostMessage(CommMessage msg);

    // used only locally so not exposed as a service method
    CommMessage GetMessage();

    [OperationContract]
    bool openFileForWrite(string fileName);
    [OperationContract]
    bool writeFileBlock(byte[] block);
    [OperationContract]
    void closeFile();
}
```

Inside the `Sender` class there's a connect function which uses the `Icommunicator channel` member directly to call the `PostMessage` function.

```
    // attempts to connect to Receiver instance
    // attempts a finite number of times to connect to a Receiver
    // first attempt to send will throw exception of no listener
    // at the specified endpoint
    // to test that we attempts to send a connect message
    public bool connect(string toAddress)
    {
        int timeToSleep = 500;
        CreateSendChannel(toAddress);
        CommMessage connectMsg = new CommMessage(CommMessage.MessageType.connect);
        connectMsg.to = toAddress;
        connectMsg.from = fromAddress;
        connectMsg.command = Msg.Command.connect;
        

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                channel.PostMessage(connectMsg);
                tryCount = 0;
                lastUrl = toAddress;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (++tryCount < maxCount)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(timeToSleep);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastError = ex.Message;
                    lastUrl = "";
                    tryCount = 0;
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what is happening here I'm not inheriting from the `Icommunicator` interface but I'm using it to call one of its function, so which function gets called in this case ?

When I ran it with a debugger it did not step into a function, yet it was still able to send a message.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it uses private variables under the same class and is called by accessing members and their method names.

Comment: @Jiayao that is correct.